Laravel: How to insert entries into a specific table
There is an issue with inserting entries into a specific table.
Usual methodology (model)

Creation of an table (portfolio_item)
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('portfolio_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('introduction');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('customer_name');
            $table->string('customer_picture');
            $table->date('creation_date');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->string('extra_property');
            $table->string('used_technology');
            $table->string('tag');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('portfolio_item');
    }
};



Creation of an model (portfolioItem)
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class portfolioItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}



Creation of a factory (portfolioItemFactory)
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
* @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\portfolioItem>
*/
class portfolioItemFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'id'=> fake()->unique()->numberBetween($min = 0, $max = 1000),
            'title' => fake()->name(),
            'introduction' => fake()->paragraph(),
            'description' => fake()->paragraph(),
            'customer_name' => fake()->name(),
            'customer_picture' => fake()->paragraph(),
            'creation_date' => '2024-07-12',
            'type' => fake()->name(),
            'extra_property' => fake()->paragraph(),
            'used_technology' => fake()->paragraph(),
            'tag' => 'laravel, api, backend'
        ];
    }
}



Execution
portfolioItem::factory(20)->create();





Issue

An error is thrown out: Table 'laravel.portfolio_items' is not found

The naming should be done differently, hence the error is thrown out.


Alternative methodology (DB)
DB::table('portfolio_item') -> insert([
    your data here
])

Issue

Would like to be able to generate 10+ entries from the get go, i.e. use the factory method, without having to write every single entry


Question

Model: How to insert the entries into a specific table, without having to deal with the renamings i.e. table 'portfolio_item' -> 'portfolio_items', 'portfolioItem' -> 'PortfolioItem'

DB: How to generate 10+ entries (the same way as the factory method) and insert it into a specific table


What did i try

I tried both the DB and the Model ways, described above


Solution to the model methodology
How to change Laravel model's table name - via the addition to the model-file, of the desired table name i.e: 'portfolio_item'
Model: portfolioItem.php
    class portfolioItem extends Model
   {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'portfolio_item';
   }

One could solve the methodology model issue.
Now the only thing that remains is the methodology DB way, as described above.

Thank you @ArunAS, it helped solve the methodology model. The only thing remaining is the methodology DB.

use Laravel's conventions of naming Models and tables
